# Python two multidimensional array creation

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

My program uses the code below to insert an object named `Field` to a multidimensional array that is created on the fly (at least I thought it would be created):

```
for x in range(self.width):
    for y in range(self.height):
            self.board_fields[x][y] = Field()
```

So `board_fields` wasn't created on the fly and I got the error:

> AttributeError: 'Board' object has no attribute 'board_fields'

How should I define the multidimensional array before putting values into it?

Comment: Are you sure that the above mentioned code got executed? Because, the error makes me feel that, python doesn't even know what `board_fields` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.board_fields = [[Field() for j in range(self.height)] for i in range(self.width)]
```

Comment: Upvoted :) Is there any other way in which I can create multi-dimensional arrays, with just default python libraries?

Comment: Aside from list comprehensions (which I used above), you could use nested *for* loops (like @astex's solution). For an arbitrary number of dimensions, you could write a recursive function that accepts a list of dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

These aren't really arrays in the classical sense, but lists of lists.  While this is a semantic difference in some contexts, here it affects where within the lists assignment can be made.  The append statement allocates additional memory to the list and assigns its argument to that new 'slot'.

```
self.board_fields = []
for x in range( self.width ):
    board_fields_sub = []
    for y in range( self.height ):
        board_fields_sub.append( Field() )
    self.board_fields.append( board_fields_sub )
```

Comment: if you mean to add the line `self.board_fields =[]` then I get the error `self.board_fields[x][y] = Field()
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: @Tom No, that’s not enough. An empty list has still no items so indexing will fail. astex creates empty lists and then appends the items to that.